# How to create a color picker in three.js and that will allows users to change the color of a particular polygon of Maya 3D Model?

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js

I am new to three.js and webGL. 
I want a sample code on how to add color picker in three.js. It has to pick/add the color like Silver, Gold, Red, Blue, purple or any color.
From there, able to change the color of a particular material(part of the model) of Maya 3D Model by choosing the color from a color picker.

I have modeled 3D complex in Maya 2014 and I exported it into webGL.

like in this example : http://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshPhongMaterial

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DAT.GUI` library, that is the same used in your example.

This is a basic tutorial of how use it in your three.js code:

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/14/dat-gui-simple-ui-for-demos/

Example code for color pickers:

```
var FizzyText = function() {

  this.color0 = "#ffae23"; // CSS string
  this.color1 = [ 0, 128, 255 ]; // RGB array
  this.color2 = [ 0, 128, 255, 0.3 ]; // RGB with alpha
  this.color3 = { h: 350, s: 0.9, v: 0.3 }; // Hue, saturation, value

  // Define render logic ...

};

window.onload = function() {

  var text = new FizzyText();
  var gui = new dat.GUI();

  gui.addColor(text, 'color0');
  gui.addColor(text, 'color1');
  gui.addColor(text, 'color2');
  gui.addColor(text, 'color3');

};
```

At this [link](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) you can see the entire example.